# Take list of tibbles in R, summarize them two different ways, then write each summary as a separate sheet on an excel file named after each tibble

Tags: r, excel, list, tibble

I have a list of tibbles. I want to summarize these tibbles in different ways and write these summaries to an excel workbook for each tibble.

For example, I want the total of each type of item in colA (how many ABs, how many BAs etc.) I also want the total of each type of item in colC.
 I then want these totals for each type as a kind of table (or df).

I want to take these summary tables and have them be written as separate sheets on an excel workbook named by each tibble. In this example
I would want 3 different work books (one for tibble 1 , one for tibble 2, one for tibble 3). Each tibble would have two sheets (one for a totals summary from colA and one that's a totals summary from colC). Each sheet would be named corresponding to the tibble's title (1,2,3).
How do I do this?

Thank you for your time and thoughts.

```
`1` <- tibble(colA = c("AB", "AB", "BA", "BA"), colB = c("K", "K", "K", "K"), colC=c("TP", "TP", "ND", "ND") )
`2` <- tibble(colA = c("CD", "AB", "BA", "BA"), colB = c("L", "L", "L", "L"), colC=c("TP", "ND", "ND", "ND") )
`3` <- tibble(colA = c("CD", "AB", "BA"), colB = c("M", "M", "M"), colC=c("TP", "ND", "ND"))

MyList <- list(`1`, `2`, `3`)

MyList

MyList
[[1]]# A tibble: 4 × 3 
colA colB colC 
<chr> <chr> <chr>
1 AB K TP 
2 AB K TP 
3 BA K ND 
4 BA K ND 

[[2]]# A tibble: 4 × 3 
colA colB colC 
<chr> <chr> <chr>
1 CD L TP 
2 AB L ND 
3 BA L ND 
4 BA L ND 

[[3]]# A tibble: 3 × 3 
colA colB colC 
<chr> <chr> <chr>
1 CD M TP 
2 AB M ND 
3 BA M ND
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We loop over the `list` (after naming it), `select` the columns of interest, split the data into a list of tibbles with `split.default`, loop over the inner list, get the `count` of the column, store the output in an object 'out'.  Loop over the sequence of the output, write the inner list elements as sheets in the work book created with `write.xlsx`. As these are already named, the sheets will be named with the corresponding column name

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(openxlsx)
names(MyList) <- seq_along(MyList)
 out <- map(MyList, ~ .x %>%
    select(colA, colC) %>%
    split.default(names(.)) %>%
     map(~ .x %>%
        count(across(everything()))) )
for(i in seq_along(out))
   write.xlsx(out[[i]], paste0(names(MyList)[i], ".xlsx"))
```

Comment: Thanks! This gets me closer. Do you know how I would then use these two generated lists of counts and write them so that each tibble (not column) was an excel workbook (with each sheet as a different column summary from that tibble)?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. This looks more promising but I get an error that says "Error in if (file.exists(file) & !overwrite) {: the condition has length >1"

Comment: @ksweet there was a typo, `names(MyList)` should be `names(MyList)[i]`

Comment: @akun Apologies, I posted before I finished accidentally. This works great, thank you. I realized that there were some additional working parts to my problem. I thought the additional information was sufficiently different so I posted the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75607315/take-a-data-frame-and-summarize-it-in-multiple-ways-based-on-a-unique-value-foun